# Com extrair lista de um link

Tags: php, html

Comprei uma api de proxy e toda vez que dou `F5` ele me dá uma nova lista de proxy. Como posso fazer um PHP que dê um `curl` e extraia toda essa lista para uma `textarea` a cada um minuto (é o tempo de espera para que a lista atualize) ?

Ex: Dei submit no meu PHP, ele puxou a lista, ele aguarda um minuto e puxa de novo automaticamente.
Este é o código html do link (Dentro do pre fica a lista de proxy)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">

</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adicione a lista de proxy, assim ficará mais fácil. Não precisa postar os IP's/endereço do proxy, utilize "X" para oculta-los.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma **[Expressão Regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular)** para capturar todos esses dados. Dessa forma você poderá filtrar o conteúdo facilmente.

A forma mais simples de capturar esses valores com o `PHP`, é utilizar a função **[preg_match_all](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)**.

Para isso você precisaria definir o `regex (Expressão Regular)` para o próprio algoritmo do `PHP`, fazer as buscas e retornar os valores.

### Capturando os proxies da API

**proxies.php**:

```
<?php

// Aqui seria a requisição para capturar a lista de proxy
$proxies = file_get_contents("proxies.html");

// Expressão Regular
$regex = <<<REGEX
[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}:[\d]{2,5}
REGEX;

// Aqui o código filtrar os valores da variável $proxies, conforme o regex e depois irá retornar os valores para a variável $results
preg_match_all("/{$regex}/", $proxies, $results);

// Imprimi na tela
echo implode("\n", reset($results));
```

> Esse regex é bem simples, mas recomendo a leitura do artigo **[How to Find or Validate an IP Address](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)**. Nele você aprenderá como capturar somente IP's válidos.
>
> Caso tenha interesse você pode acessar o site do **[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LESPLO/2/debugger)** para saber como o regex acima funciona. O passo a passo dele.

---

### Atualizando os proxies a cada min.

**index.html**

*Aqui será um código bem básico mesmo.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea id="results"></textarea>
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myscript.js**

Para executar o código a cada "x" tempo, utilize a função **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)**. Para isso basta passar a função e o tempo (em milissegundos)

```
var results    = document.querySelector("#results");

setInterval(function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.addEventListener("loadend", function(request) {
        results.value += request.target.response+"\n";
    });

    req.open("GET", "/index2.php");
    req.send();
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Em relação ao "um minuto" (a cada um minuto a lista de socks atualiza) como posso fazer para atualizar automaticamente a cada um minuto ? Obrigado!!!

Comment: E em questão a construir um HTML para eu dar submit em um botão de uma form (por exemplo action="/pegarproxies.php") e aparecer em uma textarea ?

Comment: @ISABELADESOUZARAMOSDASILV atualizei minha resposta. Adicionei um breve código para ir pegando a lista atualizada e ir adicionando no textarea automaticamente. A lógica é a mesma para utilizar com um botão.

Comment: Valdeir, criei um myscript.js, index.html e proxies.php e colei os códigos que você disponibilizou. Quando tento acessar a index.html aparece isso: "var results = document.querySelector("#results"); setInterval(function() { var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); req.addEventListener("loadend", function(request) { results.value += request.target.response+"\n"; }); req.open("GET", "/index2.php"); req.send(); }, 60 * 1000);"

Comment: Desculpa pela a falta da minima noção de programação, é que estou iniciando ainda, grata desde já!

Comment: @ISABELADESOUZARAMOSDASILV Tranquilo, o pessoal está para aprender e ensinar. Essa informação apareceu no navegador? Adicione o script abaixo do textarea, como no exemplo. Verifique também se não está faltando ou sobrando caracteres.

Comment: Já consegui, editei o código está assim agora:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea id="results"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: myscript.js: var results    = document.querySelector("#results");

setInterval(function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.addEventListener("loadend", function(request) {
        results.value += request.target.response+"\n";
    });

    req.open("GET", "/proxies.php");
    req.send();
}, 60 * 1000);

Comment: e proxies.php: <?php

// Aqui seria a requisição para capturar a lista de proxy
$proxies = file_get_contents("proxies.html");

// Expressão Regular
$regex = <<<REGEX
[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}:[\d]{2,5}
REGEX;

// Aqui o código filtrar os valores da variável $proxies, conforme o regex e depois irá retornar os valores para a variável $results
preg_match_all("/{$regex}/", $proxies, $results);

// Imprimi na tela
echo implode("\n", reset($results));

Comment: e mesmo assim a textarea não aparece nada

Comment: Estão todos na mesma pasta!

Comment: É necessário que você espere os *60.000* milissegundos para começar a aparecer. Isso equivale a 1 minutos. Você pode substituir `60 * 1000` por `1000` e o código irá executar a cada segundo, por exemplo. Só uma observação. O `script` DEVE ficar abaixo do `textarea`.

Comment: Já consegui, muito obrigado amigo. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.x:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
x.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
x.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.x.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.x.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
x.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.x.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
x.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.x.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
x.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.x:xxxxx
xx.x.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
x.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
x.x.xxx.xx:xxxx
x.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.x.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.x.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.x.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.x.xx:xxxx
x.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.x.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
x.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.x.x:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
xx.x.x.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.x.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx"
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Este é o código que copiei do inspecionar.
Segue uma imagem do código e um pouco da página também[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se possível, evite criar respostas com informações adicionais. Sempre edite o tópico nesses casos. Só uma observação mesmo.